# Variable Scope in Java Script

Tags: scope, global-variables

Arrow_onmouseover is attached with the 'onmouseover' event of an object. I get a 'timeline is not defined' JS error when the onmouseover event occurs. I know this relates to the variable scope. How can I correct this.

```
function startloop()
{
    var changer = setInterval("changecontents();", 2000);
    var timeline = setInterval("change();", 2000);  
}

window.onload = startloop();

function arrow_onmouseover()
{ 
window.clearInterval(timeline);
window.clearInterval(changer);
}
```

Also what is the difference between a function called as Function(); and Function; . I believe this may also be relevant here since it greatly affects the scope of a variable.

ie what is the difference between

```
onclick="js();" and onclick="js;" or onclick="js"
```

where JS is a defined Java Script function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code like this.

```
var timeline,changer;
function startloop()
{
    changer = setInterval("changecontents();", 2000);
    timeline = setInterval("change();", 2000);  
}

window.onload = startloop();

function arrow_onmouseover()
{ 
window.clearInterval(timeline);
window.clearInterval(changer);
}
```

The difference between

> onclick="js();" and onclick="js;" or onclick="js"

if your js function doesn't have any parameters to receive you can simple avoid () like if you want to get the date you can call new Date(); but instead you can simply call new Date;

Comment: Thanks Murali.. Declaring Timeline and changer outside a function clears the errors, the arrow_mouseover  is also triggered on mouseover (tested using an alert message command) but that is not  stopping changecontents() and chnage() from recurring. It acts as though the variables declared outside the function are different from those declared inside startloop().

Comment: is there anything in JavaScript like the global keyword in PHP for assigning Global Scope to variables inside paranthesis ?? Pardon the fantasies

Comment: Murali's solution on declaring the variables outside paranthesis is correct. I had included 'var' while assigning values in the startloop function gave them a local scope.